# Nationality on Naturalization record Marine Court NYC?

Tags: united-states, new-york-city, naturalization, 1840s

My ancestor was born in France in 1804.  All records list France as his place of birth except his naturalization record in the Marine Court of NYC in 1841.  On that record his place of birth was listed as England.  Why?

Comment: If this is the same ancestor that you asked about in your [earlier question](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/10524/19) then my concern would be that you may be dealing with more than one person. I recommend that you provide some more details and sources within your question.

Comment: Does it specify place of birth or previous nationality

Comment: The wording on the documents is very important.  Many naturalization papers ask the petitioner to state the country of allegiance.  For example, many researchers get tripped up when looking for people born in Ireland, whose pre-1906 naturalization papers say their country of allegiance is Great Britain.  Could you post a transcription or a snippet that shows exactly what the document says? You need not post your ancestor's name.